# auto reload 'php' in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am developing my laravel app. I have this function in javascript-

```
function abc(){
   var x = '<?php ($user && ($user->first_name == "" || $user->number == "")) ?>';
}
```

Now, **when the page is loaded**, the variable `'x'` is loaded with either `'1'` or `'0'`. **I want the php to be rendered everytime I call the function abc()**. So, *for instance*, at time of page load `'x'` is `'1'` but if the function is called after 20 secs of page load, I want the php to be rendered, **so that the value of `'x'` can change based on the changes happening on server** in those 20 secs.

Btw, I am aware of ajax. I am asking if there is some simpler solution.

Comment: Not possible at client side, reload the page or take a look at [ajax](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).

Comment: @halkujabra I'm not sure what you mean by a smaller solution, AJAX for this isn't as complicated.

Comment: There is no simpler solution unfortunately. PHP is rendered on page load. If you want Javascript to be changing with server changes you'll need to use something like Ajax.

Comment: Ajax is the simplest way. PHP tag can not be rendered in client side. Whatever you do, it will not work here.

Answer (score 1):

```
function abc(){
  $.ajax({url:"phpfile.php",success:function(result){
    $("div").html(result);
  }});
} 

setTimeout(function(){ abc(); },20000);
```

Try this using ajax

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without AJAX because the JavaScript code is static once loaded on the client browser. The values do not change unless *additional script executes to override those values asynchronously*.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Laravel, take a look at setting up a route to return the value you're looking for. There are plenty of examples here: http://laravel.com/docs/routing . As your example is referring to users, take a look at this doc on RESTful controllers, as the example there is specifically a UserController. http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Something like this would let you grab the data you need on the PHP-side (I'm assuming you're checking if the user's initialized):

```
class UserController extends BaseController {
    /* other controller logic above here.. */

    public function getInitStatus($id)
    {
        $user = /* Whatever code you get the user with based on ID */
        return Response::json($user && ($user->first_name == "" || $user->number == "");
    }

}
```

Then setup a route like:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

Now that you're set on the server-side, there are plenty of ways to just call it in JS (e.g. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ ).

```
function abc() {
    $.getJSON( "/users/" + userID, function( x ) { /* do whatever you were going to do with x */ });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the way to go. Please take a look into other answers.

This is answer is not a general good approach, but it answers what you *exactly* ask. Im just posting this cause i don't know what you have in mind so *it may be usefull for you.*

start by putting your js function in onload of body and change the name a bit

`<body onload="original_abc()">`

then change your js function name accordingly

```
function original_abc(){
    var x = '<?php ($user && ($user->first_name == "" || $user->number == "")) ?>';
}
```

now use this with the name of your original function

```
function abc()
{
    location.reload();
}
```

as a result, everytime you call `abc()` the page will reload, and the function `original_abc` will execute.

may be useful in some *very specific cases*, but in general, use **ajax.**